# Grouped Boxplot doesn't produce the correct x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get the boxplot grouped with Year as the x-axis but I want it grouped by "Good". If you graph the code the below, you'll see that the x-axis is No and Yes, but it is technically grouped correctly.

```
ggplot(foodprofile.both.good.bad, aes(x = Good, y = beta, color = Good)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = Year))
```

When I use the ggplot code above, the grouping is correct but the x-axis isn't correct. Here's the photo of what the graph looks like: [image] I want the grouping to be the same but I want the x-axis to say 1996, 2012, 2016, 2017 (in that order).

Here is my datafile:

```
> dput(foodprofile.both.good.bad)
structure(list(Year = structure(c(13L, 13L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("2021", 
"2003", "2015", "2002", "2007", "2005", "2006", "2008", "2010", 
"2001", "1995", "1999", "1996", "1994", "2016", "2018", "1998", 
"2014", "2011", "2012", "2017", "1997", "2009", "2019", "2013", 
"2004"), class = "factor"), PVC = structure(c(214L, 33L, 113L, 
48L, 240L, 246L, 196L, 182L, 250L, 120L, 201L, 223L, 180L, 187L, 
202L, 184L, 257L, 146L, 163L, 238L, 195L, 83L, 185L, 232L, 117L, 
228L, 247L, 167L), .Label = c("24N", "24V", "29A", "29B", "2CF", 
"2D3", "2D5", "2F1", "2HX", "2HZ", "2JJ", "2JR", "31Z", "332", 
"355", "35J", "38A", "38L", "3A3", "3AR", "3CF", "3CN", "3CZ", 
"3M4", "54B", "56P", "57F", "6,005,684", "6005445", "6007961", 
"6013120", "6013176", "6013925", "601404", "601435", "6014829", 
"6014959", "6019049", "6020617", "6021051", "62X", "634", "65W", 
"66V", "6A2", "6BM", "6BZ", "6C9", "6HU", "6JY", "6N9", "6NV", 
"6P2", "6UB", "6XB", "6Y5", "6YT", "A2J", "A34", "A3H", "A3J", 
"A4N", "A83", "A8S", "A8T", "A8X", "A93", "A9T", "AA2B", "AA2R", 
"AA3X", "AA5B", "AA6", "AA61", "AA6X", "AA7A", "AA7F", "AA7R", 
"AA9C", "AAAT", "AAAU", "AAB0", "AABB", "AABF", "AAD4", "AAR8", 
"AASC", "AASN", "AASV", "AAVW", "AAWV", "AB4D", "AB4H", "AB74", 
"AB83", "ABAB", "ABAU", "ABCD", "ABCT", "ABD", "ABHC", "ABJ", 
"ABM7", "ABWD", "ABWU", "AC0P", "AC8T", "ACH2", "ACJA", "ACL", 
"ACLS", "ACX", "AD18", "AD2B", "AD3X", "AD4A", "AD52", "AD6N", 
"ADFY", "ADHY", "ADLB", "AF18", "AF5", "AFJF", "AFM3", "AFPU", 
"AFRM", "AFT2", "AFUF", "AFX7", "AFXF", "AFY", "AFZS", "AH1C", 
"AH44", "AH5", "AH6", "AHD0", "AHF3", "AHV", "AL1T", "AL3", "AL4", 
"ALSM", "ALT5", "AM0Z", "AM1", "AM42", "AM90", "AMC3", "AMXX", 
"AMXZ", "AMZT", "AN0W", "AN9U", "ANJ", "ANU1", "ANWH", "ANY", 
"ANZ", "AP0W", "AP1D", "AP6Z", "AP8", "APH", "APM0", "APMY", 
"APXH", "AR0Z", "AR4F", "AR9J", "ARA", "ARZ9", "AS1P", "AS2H", 
"AS38", "ASAN", "ASRL", "AST5", "ASU9", "ASUW", "AT4Y", "AT5H", 
"AT6B", "AT9F", "ATDJ", "ATL8", "ATW9", "AU0", "AUR", "AV3H", 
"AVC", "AVFP", "AW5", "AXZ0", "AXZ8", "AY0P", "AYFU", "AZ2", 
"AZ55", "AZTN", "AZUU", "B0C", "B0W", "B1A", "B2B", "B3J", "B3P", 
"B47", "B4M", "B4U", "B4V", "B6H", "B7L", "B8C", "B92", "B9L", 
"B9X", "BA4", "BA8L", "BABT", "BAU", "BAXH", "BB4", "BBB", "BBCH", 
"BBRD", "BBSY", "BC4", "BC9M", "BD1", "BDCR", "BHD", "BHT", "BJ5", 
"BJN", "BL1", "BL6M", "BLA", "BLU4", "BLVR", "BLW0", "BM3", "BMU", 
"BMWZ", "BN14", "BPC3", "BPFD", "BPP", "BPT1", "BPU", "BR3", 
"BR57", "BRUN", "BSA2", "BT3T", "BT88", "BTHC", "BTU", "BV0U", 
"BV12", "BV5", "BVUA", "BW9", "BX4", "BXPL", "BXPV", "BXT", "BY0", 
"BY7", "BY8", "BYX", "BZU", "CATA", "F1X", "FCF", "FCS", "FDH", 
"FFR", "FFV", "FJ0", "FL8", "FLM", "FM1", "FN6", "FND", "FNJ", 
"FS0", "FS3", "FS4", "FSC", "FSR", "FU5", "FUJ", "FW2", "FYR", 
"FZ8", "H02", "H2C", "H3J", "H57", "H60", "H7J", "H7M", "H80", 
"H87", "HA0", "HB2", "HBL", "HC1", "HCM", "HCN", "HD3", "HD9", 
"HDD", "HDT", "HDZ", "HFS", "HH4", "HH8", "HHC", "HJW", "HL5", 
"HLJ", "HMB", "HNT", "HNU", "HPT", "HR5", "HU0", "HY1", "J12", 
"J4H", "JRBV", "JSJ", "NAJB", "NAZB", "NAZJ", "NAZR", "NAZV", 
"S2Y", "S4P", "S4T", "S5P", "S60", "SAB", "SBS", "SCY", "SF0", 
"SHJ", "SJ1", "SJX", "SL5", "SLN", "SMD", "SMM", "SP3", "SRM", 
"SUL", "SX5", "SY3", "UF9", "UHA", "UHT", "UJ6", "UL2", "ULN", 
"UM9", "UR5", "UR9", "USM", "UT2", "UTS", "UU9", "UUC", "UUR", 
"UVF", "UX8", "UXA", "UXJ", "UXL", "UXY", "W1V", "W2J", "W30", 
"W3U", "W45", "W46", "X24", "X31", "X3T", "X7U", "XFS", "XH3", 
"XL3", "XLV", "XP7", "XPT", "XT1", "XVZ", "XXN", "XXS", "Z0C", 
"Z83", "Z8T", "Z8V", "ZAT", "ZCD", "ZCN", "ZCW", "ZDH", "ZFN", 
"ZHD", "ZJ0", "ZJA", "ZL4", "ZLV", "ZN4", "ZNC", "ZNP", "ZSJ", 
"ZSS", "ZT2", "ZTJ", "ZVA", "ZYR"), class = "factor"), totalV = c(162.3112421, 
182.0570588, 171.4040816, 195.2775688, 175.3824741, 185.0333716, 
197.9806171, 111.5943309, 109.7481209, 135.4582258, 184.6335629, 
127.2468355, 174.4103694, 205.5227986, 196.7908468, 171.7465149, 
122.5651423, 171.6944144, 125.9634657, 153.5071373, 185.7648224, 
122.032622, 186.3985479, 200.7254018, 209.7205751, 181.0741487, 
129.1644314, 192.4846995), beta = c(0.939545409183473, 0.903101427698009, 
0.920597194775432, 0.975569706601411, 0.961566778917932, 0.962416894429062, 
0.926286458418281, 0.902768013, 0.987496208, 0.999816992, 0.87713293711278, 
1.006513207, 1.01945454751317, 1.01074464229568, 0.941767755307939, 
0.92560465408643, 1.020815143, 0.924856435488739, 1.124617445, 
1.28187117121599, 0.839260436297094, 1.054191798, 0.865135683485324, 
0.959481493770363, 1.0008212961514, 0.890698343192179, 0.993472305, 
0.863238534483954), Age = c(8, 9, 11, 16, 4, 4, 9, 10, 4, 15, 
7, 8, 12, 12, 7, 12, 3, 14, 13, 6, 10, 17, 11, 7, 16, 7, 5, 13
), correct = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("yes", "no"), class = "factor"), Clutch = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("3", 
"2"), class = "factor"), AverageV = c(54.10374737, 60.6856862733333, 
57.1346938766667, 65.0925229433333, 58.4608247133333, 61.6777905266667, 
65.9935390433333, 55.79716547, 54.87406044, 67.7291129, 61.5445209666667, 
63.62341777, 58.1367897933333, 68.5075995333333, 65.59694894, 
57.2488383066667, 61.28257115, 57.2314714566667, 62.98173285, 
51.1690457533333, 61.92160747, 61.01631099, 62.1328493033333, 
66.9084672733333, 69.90685836, 60.35804956, 64.5822157, 64.1615664966667
), beta.year = c(0.0163698936280629, 0.0157349226149869, 0.0161127527306381, 
0.015595680652645, 0.0153718266452113, 0.0153854167863768, 0.0148078273654958, 
0.0151810476205676, 0.0166058464000739, 0.0168130340783404, 0.0140220479219088, 
0.0160535463986777, 0.016458741055718, 0.0163181226486058, 0.0152045146662489, 
0.0149435669875995, 0.0162816574573008, 0.0149314872571372, 0.0179372691868412, 
0.0206953666794657, 0.0135495694565473, 0.016814003854694, 0.0139673163725454, 
0.015490496846811, 0.0161579136574416, 0.0143800166717758, 0.0158455484073134, 
0.0139366875581133), Age2 = c(64, 81, 121, 256, 16, 16, 81, 100, 
16, 225, 49, 64, 144, 144, 49, 144, 9, 196, 169, 36, 100, 289, 
121, 49, 256, 49, 25, 169), Age_Group_3 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Old", "Young", 
"Middle"), class = "factor"), Age_Group_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Older", 
"Young"), class = "factor"), FPC_LA = c(0.028, 0.028, 0.02, 0.067, 
0.067, 0.067, 0.067, 0.067, 0.067, 0.067, 0.067, 0.072, 0.072, 
0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 
0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072), FPC_LA_normalised = c(-0.119, 
-0.119, -0.579, 2.085, 2.085, 2.085, 2.085, 2.085, 2.085, 2.085, 
2.085, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 
2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335, 2.335
), FPC_total = c(0.023, 0.023, 0.01, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 
0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 
0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 
0.019, 0.019, 0.019), FPC_total_normalised = c(1.115, 1.115, 
-0.967, 0.239, 0.239, 0.239, 0.239, 0.239, 0.239, 0.239, 0.239, 
0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 
0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552), Good = c("No", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I would suggest you for including in your question a clue (a handmade draw maybe) of what you are expecting for.

Comment: In the code above you are explicitly indicating X axis being 'Good' instead of 'Year' (that is what `x = Good` means in ggplot). That is why I'm suggesting to include a handmade draw of what you are expecting for.

Answer (score 2):

You should assign Year to `x`, also suggested by @Wencheng, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
foodprofile.both.good.bad$Year <- factor(foodprofile.both.good.bad$Year, levels=unique(foodprofile.both.good.bad$Year))
ggplot(foodprofile.both.good.bad, aes(x = Year, y = beta, fill = Good)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've done that before, but it's not in the correct order. I want the 1996 and the 2012 to be next to eachother.

Comment: Hi @Cassidy, check my edited answer. It changed the order by using `factor`.